# Fading in page on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

I am trying to use j-query to fade in my pages body upon load, however for some reason the body's background image is not being affected by the j-query. Please see the code I have below:

J-Query Code in head section:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').fadeIn(2000);
});
</script>
```

CSS Code:

```
body
{
overflow:hidden;
background:url('body.png') no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
display:none;
}
```

Everything contained within the body (div's / paragraphs / headings etc) fade in on load as per the j-query code, however the body's background image (body.png) loads instantly with the page. Please can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong with the above code?

Comment: you can fade html instead of body [http://jsfiddle.net/GtBPe/](http://jsfiddle.net/GtBPe/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`body` behaves funny.  You would need to wrap the contents of the entire page in another `div` and fade that in.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        # Page Contents #
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    background-image:url('some-image.jpg');
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn();
});
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robbiewxyz/H63kr/).

Comment: Thanks for this, i'll go ahead with the wrapper idea. Cheers

Comment: JSFiddle link broken

Comment: @JaydenLawson hey, thanks man!  I'd changed my username, but it's back to working now.

Comment: No worries Robbie Wxyz!  Great work on fixing so quick :)

Answer (score 1):

Like the @ITFarmer wait, you can do it in CSS3, but you could probably also animate the background-image with CSS3 too.

```
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeinbg {
    from {
        background-image: none;
    }
    to {
        background:url('body.png') no-repeat;
    }
}

.container {
    animation: fadein 2s;
}

.body {
    animation: fadeinbg 2s;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would also affect the background image, but you could do the fade-in effect also without jQuery. At least in browsers which support CSS3:

```
@keyframes fadein{
   from{opacity:0;}
   to{opacity:1;}
}
.someElement{
   animation: fadein 2s;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this - the body background image still loads instantly, but its good to know that the fade funtiopn is achievable using key-frames as well as Jquery :-)